# How to join (draw new) lines that are close but not touching - large dataset

Tags: qgis

As per the picture below I've got 2 lines that are very close but not touching (0.013mm) in a T-junction format but could be any kind of intersection.

> ```
>       |                           |                   |
> ----  |   needs to become   ------|    ...or    ------|-- 
>       |                           |                   |
> ```

I don't know how many there are of these (10k features in total in this dataset) but it's breaking a path finding algorithm so need them to magically get joined together.

A new line segment is fine but moving the existing one would be better (as as not to increase the existing number of features unnecessarily).

I looked at snapping but it appears that would then be a manual operation which is not ideal (as there are potentially multiple datasets all with 10K plus features) though could work if I can generate a list of these 'near but not touching' lines and there are not many of them.

I'm wondering if there's any buffering function that could do it but then not sure how to move the existing node or create the new line based on that.

Any thoughts on how to do this as a bulk operation in QGIS (3.4.11)

Thanks in advance!!

[image: Close but not touching]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V.Clean - snapping seems to have solved my issue.

The threshold is in map units and being WGS 84 that is degrees so I opted for 0.0000001° = 0.01 m

Seems to have done the job, it moved the old line (orange) on the right  0.013mm to the left to meet the end of the other node - new line in red

[image]